# ASP.net access a master page variable through content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, master-pages

I have a master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Codefile="AdminMaster.master.cs" Inherits="AlphaPackSite.MasterPages.AdminMaster" %>
```

Then I have a public variable:

```
public partial class AdminMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected bool blnShowDialogue = false;
```

In my *content page* I would like to set this variable:

```
blnShowDialogue = true;
```

So that in my master page I can have the code:

```
    $(function() {
    <%if(blnShowDialogue == true){%>
        $("#dialog").dialog();
    <% } %>
    }
```

Does this make sense?  When I try combinations of Master.blnShowDialogue, or blnShowDialogue = , etc etc nothing seems to work.

> The name 'blnShowDialogue' does not
>   exist in the current context

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use @MasterType directive, as explained here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx

Comment: Youre right, didn't even notice that was missing in his declaration. +1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still a bit lost with this!  Where do I put that directive?

Comment: Hi Tom, you have to put it under your @page directive, in your .aspx pages.

Comment: Thanks, I do that <%@ MasterType TypeName="AdminMaster" %> on my content page but ((AdminMaster)Master).blnShowDialogue = true; doesn't work still , type or namespace not found

Comment: @Tom - get rid of the casting to (AdminMaster). Just use "Master.blnShowDialogue". I assume the "AdminMaster" class is in the same namespace as the page you're trying to access it from? If not, you will need to use the "VirtualPath" attribute (as opposed to TypeName).

Answer (score 6):

You need to cast the Master page to the actual type.

```
((AdminMaster)Master).blnShowDialogue = "Foo";
```

Otherwise **Master** will simply be referring to the base class **Master** - you're trying to access a property in your actual class which *derives* from the **Master** class.

The error you are getting is because a property called **blnShowDialogue** does not exist in the class **System.Web.UI.MasterPage** - which makes sense, as you're not telling it which specific MasterPage instance you are trying to refer to.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it gives the error, The type or namespace name 'AdminMaster' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Tom - @mamoo's answer is correct (didnt look at your Master page directive closely enough), give his way a go.