# Get Public Content Page Variable into Masterpage

Tags: c#, master-pages, content-pages

I have a public variable in my content page that I need to access in my MasterPage. So I can set a Javascript variable... .

How can I reference a public content page variable from the masterpage?.

Comment: this is not that difficult.. have you done a google search..? there are plenty of examples out there here is one of the examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651326/asp-net-access-a-master-page-variable-through-content-page

Answer (score 1):

I supposed you want to say that you want to access to variable in the MasterPage from Contend Page, if is correct, use this example:

Declare your public or protected variable:

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage

{
    public string strEmpresa = "NS";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Set the following directive at the beginning of your content page:

```
<%@ MasterType  virtualPath="~/MasterPage.Master"%>
```

then you can use the public variables of your MasterPage, using Master.NameVariable.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = Master.strEmpresa;
        }
    }
```

In other case if you really want access to variable in ContentPage from MasterPage, you just can set the value in Session and then read in MasterPage. For example:

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["myVariable"] != null)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = Session["myVariable"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}

 public partial class WebFormMP_TestPublicVariable : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["myVariable"] = "Test";
        }
    }

}
```

There are many ways that you can achieve this. check around internet ;).

Comment: You can also use `<%@ MasterType  TypeName="(type)" %>`.

Comment: You might want to mention that this method doesn't access the content page from the master page, instead it allows the content page to access the master page member.  Depending on the situation this might not work for the op.

Comment: yes you ok, I supposed that he want to say this. because the other case look to easy to answer. i will edit the post mentioning that thank you.